# How to connect to PostgresSQL on Heroku from a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js, heroku, sequelize.js

My app is developed using Vue, webpack, Express and PostgresSQL.
I have deployed my app to Heroku, and created a PostgresSQL database on Heroku. The picture below is the Database Credentials:
[image]

Then I configured the server of my app to connect to the PostgresSQL database on Heroku. Here is my code:

```
.
.
.
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
.
.
.
const sequelize = new Sequelize(<My database URI>, {
    dialect: "postgres",
    protocol: "postgres",
    port: 5432,
    host: "ec2-18-206-84-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    logging: true
});
.
.
.
const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
    });
});
.
.
.
```

Then I committed and pushed to Heroku, open my app, but an `Application error` occurred. And using `heroku logs --tail`, the log shows that `Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: http is not defined`.

I can see the tables have already been created on the Postgres DB on Heroku, like shown below.
[image]

Please help me with the `http is not defined` error. Where did I configure wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this to your file.

```
const http = require('http');
```

Comment: ahh please add `const http = require('http');` in your file, I think you miss it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was being stupid. I thought the error mean some URL is wrong. Please make it an answer and I will accept it!